# Sorted Doubly Linked Sentinel List merge function issue

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am working on a templated data structure class which is a doubly linked list which uses sentinel nodes.
The list is sorted based on insert() and I am working on a merge function wherein the nodes of each list must be combined into this->list. The nodes must be moved and not have new ones created. and if the same value exists in both lists the other node value must come after the current node value.

I coded what I thought was a logical implementation however the output I get is not as expected and the results do not make sense to me, so if anyone could explain how i am getting the results I have it would be greatly appreciated.

Class Definition

```
class SortedList {
    struct Node {
        T data_;
        Node* next_;
        Node* prev_;
        Node(const T& data = T{}, Node* nx = nullptr, Node* pr = nullptr) {
            data_ = data;
            next_ = nx;
            prev_ = pr;
        }
    };
    Node* front_;
    Node* back_;

public:
    class const_iterator {
        friend class SortedList;
        Node* current_;
        const_iterator(Node* n)
        {
            current_ = n;
        }
    public:
        const_iterator() {
            //Set to safe state         
            current_ = nullptr;
        }
        const_iterator& operator++() {
            current_ = current_->next_;
            return *this;
        }
        const_iterator operator++(int) {
            const_iterator old = *this;
            current_ = current_->next_;
            return old;
        }
        const_iterator& operator--() {
            current_ = current_->prev_;
            return *this;
        }
        const_iterator operator--(int) {
            const_iterator old = *this;
            current_ = current_->prev_;
            return old;
        }
        bool operator==(const_iterator rhs) {
            return (current_ == rhs.current_) ? true : false;
        }
        bool operator!=(const_iterator rhs) {
            return !(*this == rhs);
        }
        bool operator>(const_iterator rhs) {
            return current_->data_ > rhs->current_->data_;
        }
        const T& operator*()const {
            return current_->data_;
        }
    };
    class iterator :public const_iterator {
        friend SortedList;
        iterator(Node* n) :const_iterator(n) {};
    public:
        iterator() : const_iterator() {};
        //prefix
        iterator& operator++() {
            this->current_ = this->current_->next_;
            return *this;
        }
        //post-fix
        iterator operator++(int) {
            iterator old = *this;
            this->current_ = this->current_->next_;
            return old;
        }
        iterator& operator--() {
            this->current_ = this->current_->prev_;
            return *this;
        }
        iterator operator--(int) {
            iterator old = *this;
            this->current_ = this->current_->prev_;
            return old;
        }
        T& operator*() {
            return this->current_->data_;
        }
        const T& operator*()const {
            return this->current_->data;
        }
    };
    SortedList();                                   //done
    ~SortedList();
    SortedList(const SortedList& rhs);
    SortedList& operator=(const SortedList& rhs);
    SortedList(SortedList&& rhs);
    SortedList& operator=(SortedList&& rhs);
    iterator begin() {
        return iterator(front_->next_);
    }
    iterator end() {
        return iterator(back_);
    }
    const_iterator cbegin() const {
        return const_iterator(front_->next_);
    }
    const_iterator cend() const {
        return const_iterator(back_);
    }
    iterator insert(const T& data);
    iterator search(const T& data);
    const_iterator search(const T& data) const;
    iterator erase(iterator it);
    void merge(SortedList& other);
    bool empty() const;
    int size() const;
};
```

merge function

```
template <typename T>
void SortedList<T>::merge(SortedList& other) {
    
    iterator it = this->begin();
    iterator oit = other.begin();
    while (oit !=  other.end()) {               
        std::cout << *oit << " " << *it << std::endl;
        if (*oit < *it) {
            oit.current_->prev_->next_ = oit.current_->next_;
            oit.current_->next_->prev_ = oit.current_->prev_;
            oit.current_->next_ = it.current_;
            oit.current_->prev_ = it.current_->prev_;
            it.current_->next_ = oit.current_;
        }
        else {
            oit.current_->prev_->next_ = oit.current_->next_;
            oit.current_->next_->prev_ = oit.current_->prev_;
            oit.current_->next_ = it.current_->next_;
            oit.current_->prev_ = it.current_;
            it.current_->prev_ = oit.current_;
        }
        oit++;
        it++;
    }
}
```

main tester

```
int main() {
    int num[] = { 3,5,1,2,6,8,9,11 };
    int num2[] = { 1,5,4,6,12,7,8,9 };

    SortedList<int> l;
    SortedList<int> l2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        l.insert(num[i]);
        l2.insert(num2[i]);
    }
     SortedList<int>::iterator result;
     SortedList<int>::iterator result2 = l2.begin();
     result = l.begin();
     while (result != l.end()) {
         std::cout << *result << "    " << *result2 << std::endl;
         ++result;
         ++result2;
     }
     l.merge(l2);
```

output

```
1    1
2    4
3    5
5    6
6    7
8    8
9    9
11    12

1 1
2 2
3 3
5 5
6 6
8 8
9 9
11 11
0 0
```

I dont understand why my second output is showing same the same values for *it and *oit I am pretty certain the error is in how I assign the the oit.current_->next & prev but i am unsure.

any insight is appriciated.

Comment: I don't see the code that produces your second output.  Nor do I see anything attempting to use a sentinel.

Comment: You're modifying the lists while iterating it, you need to take some very good care to not destroy the lists. I suggest you first do the operation all using pen and paper. Draw boxes for the nodes, and arrows for the links. Erase and redraw the arrows as you change the pointers. And decide if the merge operation should make both lists the same, or remove the nodes from one list and move to the other.

Comment: I did the images already

Comment: I understand what is supposed to happen but I don't understand why whats happening is happening.

Comment: @MarkRansom the code for the output is in the merge function i am printing out the values with each iteration of the loop and the sentinels are in the constructor for the list.

Comment: I recommend that you start with simpler lists... First where each list have *no* nodes. Then with one list having a node, and the other none. Then the opposite. Then with two lists each having a single node. And so on, using a debugger to step through the code statement by statement, and draw the operations on paper while you stepping. And remember to draw out *all* objects and pointers.

Comment: I've already done that...

Comment: Even tried with three nodes each? That should be generic enough to handle all further cases, and yet small enough to be much easier to debug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222988/discussion-between-d0rf47-and-some-programmer-dude).