# Iterator while loop running extra loop

Tags: c++

I have a Doubly linked List class wherein i have a function which uses my classes iterators to loop over the collection. However in 1 specific place it runs for an extra loop and I cannot figure out why.

current merge template

```
template <typename T>
void DlList<T>::merge(SortedList& other) {  
    iterator it = back_->prev_;
    iterator oit = other.begin();   
    while (oit.current_->next_ != NULL) {
        std::cout << *it << "    " << *oit << std::endl;
        it.current_->next_ = oit.current_;
        back_->prev_ = oit.current_;
        //back_->prev_->next_ = back_;
        //other.back_->prev_ = other.back_->prev_->prev_;
        it++;
        oit++;
    }
}
```

It always iterates and extra time and added a null node to the list and I don't understand why.

Any insight is greatly appricicated!

Edit Added full project examples to explain intention of function
I am working on a templated data structure class which is a doubly linked list which uses sentinel nodes.
The list is sorted based on insert() and I am working on a merge function wherein the nodes of each list must be combined into this->list. The nodes must be moved and not have new ones created. and if the same value exists in both lists the other node value must come after the current node value.

I coded what I thought was a logical implementation however the output I get is not as expected and the results do not make sense to me, so if anyone could explain how i am getting the results I have it would be greatly appreciated.

Class Definition

```
class SortedList {
    struct Node {
        T data_;
        Node* next_;
        Node* prev_;
        Node(const T& data = T{}, Node* nx = nullptr, Node* pr = nullptr) {
            data_ = data;
            next_ = nx;
            prev_ = pr;
        }
    };
    Node* front_;
    Node* back_;

public:
    class const_iterator {
        friend class SortedList;
        Node* current_;
        const_iterator(Node* n)
        {
            current_ = n;
        }
    public:
        const_iterator() {
            //Set to safe state         
            current_ = nullptr;
        }
        const_iterator& operator++() {
            current_ = current_->next_;
            return *this;
        }
        const_iterator operator++(int) {
            const_iterator old = *this;
            current_ = current_->next_;
            return old;
        }
        const_iterator& operator--() {
            current_ = current_->prev_;
            return *this;
        }
        const_iterator operator--(int) {
            const_iterator old = *this;
            current_ = current_->prev_;
            return old;
        }
        bool operator==(const_iterator rhs) {
            return (current_ == rhs.current_) ? true : false;
        }
        bool operator!=(const_iterator rhs) {
            return !(*this == rhs);
        }
        bool operator>(const_iterator rhs) {
            return current_->data_ > rhs->current_->data_;
        }
        const T& operator*()const {
            return current_->data_;
        }
    };
    class iterator :public const_iterator {
        friend SortedList;
        iterator(Node* n) :const_iterator(n) {};
    public:
        iterator() : const_iterator() {};
        //prefix
        iterator& operator++() {
            this->current_ = this->current_->next_;
            return *this;
        }
        //post-fix
        iterator operator++(int) {
            iterator old = *this;
            this->current_ = this->current_->next_;
            return old;
        }
        iterator& operator--() {
            this->current_ = this->current_->prev_;
            return *this;
        }
        iterator operator--(int) {
            iterator old = *this;
            this->current_ = this->current_->prev_;
            return old;
        }
        T& operator*() {
            return this->current_->data_;
        }
        const T& operator*()const {
            return this->current_->data;
        }
    };
    SortedList();                                   //done
    ~SortedList();
    SortedList(const SortedList& rhs);
    SortedList& operator=(const SortedList& rhs);
    SortedList(SortedList&& rhs);
    SortedList& operator=(SortedList&& rhs);
    iterator begin() {
        return iterator(front_->next_);
    }
    iterator end() {
        return iterator(back_);
    }
    const_iterator cbegin() const {
        return const_iterator(front_->next_);
    }
    const_iterator cend() const {
        return const_iterator(back_);
    }
    iterator insert(const T& data);
    iterator search(const T& data);
    const_iterator search(const T& data) const;
    iterator erase(iterator it);
    void merge(SortedList& other);
    bool empty() const;
    int size() const;
};
```

first merge function attempt

```
template <typename T>
void SortedList<T>::merge(SortedList& other) {
    
    iterator it = this->begin();
    iterator oit = other.begin();
    while (oit !=  other.end()) {               
        std::cout << *oit << " " << *it << std::endl;
        if (*oit < *it) {
            oit.current_->prev_->next_ = oit.current_->next_;
            oit.current_->next_->prev_ = oit.current_->prev_;
            oit.current_->next_ = it.current_;
            oit.current_->prev_ = it.current_->prev_;
            it.current_->next_ = oit.current_;
        }
        else {
            oit.current_->prev_->next_ = oit.current_->next_;
            oit.current_->next_->prev_ = oit.current_->prev_;
            oit.current_->next_ = it.current_->next_;
            oit.current_->prev_ = it.current_;
            it.current_->prev_ = oit.current_;
        }
        oit++;
        it++;
    }
}
```

main tester

```
int main() {
    int num[] = { 3,5,1,2,6,8,9,11 };
    int num2[] = { 1,5,4,6,12,7,8,9 };

    SortedList<int> l;
    SortedList<int> l2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        l.insert(num[i]);
        l2.insert(num2[i]);
    }
     SortedList<int>::iterator result;
     SortedList<int>::iterator result2 = l2.begin();
     result = l.begin();
     while (result != l.end()) {
         std::cout << *result << "    " << *result2 << std::endl;
         ++result;
         ++result2;
     }
     l.merge(l2);
```

output

```
1    1
2    4
3    5
5    6
6    7
8    8
9    9
11    12

1 1
2 2
3 3
5 5
6 6
8 8
9 9
11 11
0 0
```

I dont understand why my second output is showing same the same values for *it and *oit I am pretty certain the error is in how I assign the the oit.current_->next & prev but i am unsure.

any insight is appriciated.

Comment: You don't need to have a loop at all for what you're doing, I don't think. To merge two lists you generally just connect the end of one with the beginning of the other, no?

Comment: For this specific class the list needs to be ordered so I will need the loop for the final code but right now I am just trying to add the the start of 1 list to the end of the other list, i am trying to get the logic of this for doubly linked lists, this is my first attempt at making a templated container class.

Comment: It seems like you're appending one doubly linked list to another by iteratively setting `next_` and `back_`. Instead just do `back_->prev_->next_ = other.begin()->next_` and `back_->prev = other.end()->prev_`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do b/c I will need to have the list in sorted order for the final code, but I am just trying to grasp the logic of shifting all the pointers without fckn up my lists

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64340891/sorted-doubly-linked-sentinel-list-merge-function-issue?noredirect=1#comment113776259_64340891
this is the original question i asked which actually explains what I am trying to do but no one really answered so I gave up and am just trying to understand the logic of everything step by step but I am really quite lost here

Comment: Inspiration to draw from [C++ Template Singly-Linked List w/Sort](https://pastebin.com/Sq1MPU15). You will have to incorporate the `->prev` pointers to make it doubly linked, but you may find some of it useful. To join the sorted sublists, you simply take list1 `tail->next` and set it equal to list2 `head` and list2 `head->prev` is set to list1 `tail`.

Comment: Thx I will take a look now.

Comment: Note, since that example uses a recursive mergesort, you are limited to lists with roughly 100,000 elements (nodes). For larger lists, the recursive sort must be replaced with an iterative mergesort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to merge two sorted doubly linked lists together. There are several problems with your approach, and so I'll show you my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    node* next;
    node* prev;
    int val;
    
    node(int i_val)
      : next(nullptr),
        prev(nullptr),
        val(i_val)
    {}
};

void connect(node* a, node* b) {
    if (a != nullptr) {
        if (a->next != nullptr) {
            a->next->prev = nullptr;
        }
        a->next = b;
    }
    if (b != nullptr) {
        if (b->prev != nullptr) {
            b->prev->next = nullptr;
        }
        b->prev = a;
    }
}

struct DlList {
    node* first_node;
    node* last_node;
    
    DlList()
      : first_node(nullptr),
        last_node(nullptr)
    {}
    
    ~DlList() {
        for (node* n = first_node; n != nullptr; n = n->next) {
            delete n->prev;
        }
        delete last_node;
    }
    
    void push(int new_val) {
        node* new_node = new node(new_val);
        connect(last_node, new_node);
        last_node = new_node;
        if (first_node == nullptr) {
            first_node = new_node;
        }
    }
    
    void merge_sorted(DlList& other) {
        node* this_node = first_node;
        node* other_node = other.first_node;
        node* n = nullptr; // goes through each node of the new list in order
        while (this_node != nullptr || other_node != nullptr) {
            node* next_n;
            if (other_node == nullptr || 
                    (this_node != nullptr && this_node->val <= other_node->val)) {
                // entered if other_node is nullptr or this_node comes before other_node
                next_n = this_node;
                this_node = this_node->next;
            }
            else {
                // entered if this_node is nullptr or other_node comes before this_node
                next_n = other_node;
                other_node = other_node->next;
            }
            connect(n, next_n);
            if (n == nullptr) { // first time through loop
                first_node = next_n;
            }
            n = next_n;
        }
        last_node = n;
        
        // *this takes ownership of all of other's nodes
        other.first_node = nullptr;
        other.last_node = nullptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "running test" << std::endl;
    
    int num[] = { 1,2,3,5,6,8,9,11 };
    int num2[] = { 1,4,5,6,7,8,9,12 };

    DlList l;
    DlList l2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        l.push(num[i]);
        l2.push(num2[i]);
    }
    l.merge_sorted(l2);
    
    for (node* n = l.first_node; n != nullptr; n = n->next) {
        std::cout << n->val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

You may add iterators and other higher-level abstractions later, but for now I think they complicate and obscure the logic. I also did not see a need for a "past-the-end-of-the-list" node in your case, as nullptr would suffice. Though of course these could rather easily be added in if you wanted them to, just for demonstration purposes they are omitted.

Notice how I made a dedicated `connect` function that does all the pointer assignments as they should be done for two nodes. It handles a bunch of combinations of nullptr cases, too, so you don't need to worry as much about checking for null pointers outside of the function. (Note how the first time through the merge loop, a null n pointer is connected to next_n). Now you hardly need to worry about pointer assignments, and it's clearer when you just say, "connect these two nodes."

My merger function goes through each node in the newly created list. It picks the next node from the two available nodes, from *this and other. It then connects the current node to the next node, and advances the current node to the next node. It has special handling when one or the other of the lists runs out (this_node or other_node becomes nullptr), which indeed happens in the given test case. It takes care to assign first_node and last_node in the correct places, and to clear other after the merge, so as to prevent double ownership issues.

Comment: my final code requires the merged list to be sorted so I will need the loop in the end but for now I just want to understand the logic of how reorganizing the pointers actually works b/c I can't get it to work properly

Comment: @d0rf47 I somewhat understand. Are we assuming that *this is also sorted, and so you're merging two sorted lists? I can show you how to do that. If you edit your question to show your final intention I could edit my answer to show you my updated solution.

Comment: I would really appreciate that I will add everything now

Comment: its there now any insight you can give me would be awesome cause I am truly stumped here

Comment: much appreciated mate!

Comment: @d0rf47 I've edited it in, if you'd like to look at it.

Comment: yeah it works for the test case, but let me ask you, and sorry i know i ask so many questions but this is all totally new to me. So if I have sentinel nodes in my list how would incorporate that cause when i run it with my class which uses sentinel nodes I still get a bunch of 0's mixed in: 0
1
1
3
5
0
5
6
I know its cause the sentinels but I dont see where they come from in that code

Comment: @d0rf47 I didn't account for any sentinel nodes in my code, no. What are your sentinel nodes supposed to represent?

Comment: Yeah no worries man! I ended up sorting everything out. But I do have a question for you if you dont mind. My professor explained to us that sentinel nodes are just empty nodes that stay in the back and front of the list and only have pointers to last and first data nodes, but when I mention sentinels on here people seem to not get what I am talking about. So what is your understanding of them then, since it seems like the definition i was given differs from its common usage at least on this site